# Automatically install unmet build dependencies as detected by dpkg-checkbuilddeps

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, dependencies

Is there a command that installs all the unmet build dependencies that `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` would list?

I tried to `sed` the output and give it to `apt-get install`, but it seems very hacky and for some reason didn't work in some environments.

```
sudo apt-get install --yes $(dpkg-checkbuilddeps | sed 's/([^)]*)//g' | sed 's/dpkg-checkbuilddeps:\serror:\sUnmet build dependencies://g')
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: similar to question https://serverfault.com/q/127625/238995

Answer (score 31):

I use `mk-build-deps` from the `devscripts` package for this (you’ll also need `equivs`).

```
mk-build-deps
```

will build a package depending on all the build-dependencies in the `debian/control` control file; that package can then be installed using `apt`, which will also install all the missing dependencies.

The advantage of this approach is that uninstalling the dependency package, once you’ve finished with it, will also identify any build-dependencies which could also be uninstalled.

To reduce manual steps, the following command can be used:

```
mk-build-deps --install --root-cmd sudo --remove
```

The end result of this is that all the build dependencies are installed, but not the newly-generated build-dependency package itself: it’s installed (`--install`), along with all its dependencies, and then removed (`--remove`), but the dependencies are left in place.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps 2>&1 | sed 's/dpkg-checkbuilddeps:\serror:\sUnmet build dependencies: //g' | sed 's/[\(][^)]*[\)] //g'
```

First of all, `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` prints out the error to `stderr` not `stdout`. So it needs to be redirected to `stdout` to use pipeline.

Here is how to [Redirect `stderr` and `stdout` in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-bash)

You used the regex `([^)]*)` on:

```
sed 's/([^)]*)//g'
```

But it should be:

```
sed 's/[\(][^)]*[\)]//g'
```

Reference: [Using sed to delete a string between parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825977/using-sed-to-delete-a-string-between-parentheses)

Answer (score 1):

Combining the 2 methods previously mentioned worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install \
    --yes $(dpkg-checkbuilddeps 2>&1 | sed -e 's/dpkg-checkbuilddeps:\serror:\sUnmet build dependencies: //g' -e  's/[\(][^)]*[\)] //g')
```

Comment: This does not work when the last dependency in the line has a version specifier (e.g. `... packagename (>= 1.0.0)` because of the mandatory white space at the end of the second regular expression. Use `'s/[\(][^)]*[\)] *//g'` to cover this case.