# Automatically install multiple packages under one custom meta-package

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg

It is required to install a bunch of packages when building a project.
Such projects may have dedicated Docker images for this or pre-existing meta-packages.

But for the ones that have none of the above, you have to **manually** install the required packages. For example, if you want to install the dependencies to build the [PPSSPP](https://github.com/hrydgard/ppsspp/wiki/Build-instructions#prerequisites) project, you have to run (as of 2020-06-02):

`sudo apt install build-essential cmake libgl1-mesa-dev libsdl2-dev libvulkan-dev`

The more projects you build from scratch, the more dependency packages you install on your system, losing track of why `libsdl2-dev` is **manually** installed on your system.

Is there an existing tool (or `apt` command) that install a group of packages **automatically** under a given group name, for example by automatically creating a meta-package depending on all given packages, with a given name:

`sudo my-apt-tool install custom-ppsspp-metapkg build-essential cmake (...)`

That way, when you remove `custom-ppsspp-metapkg`, the no longer useful dependency packages are marked as no longer required by APT.

Or... is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for build dependencies, there’s already a tool for that, or near enough; `mk-build-deps` (in `devscripts`) will create a meta-package encapsulating another package’s build-dependencies, so you can then install the meta-package and have any dependencies be automatically installed (and then become autoremoval candidates when the meta-package is removed). See [Automatically install unmet build dependencies as detected by dpkg-checkbuilddeps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416457/86440) for details.

In other scenarios, you could use `equivs`. See [Create a .deb package with only dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318117/86440) for details.