# How to install packages via Apt with our intention stated?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, dependencies

## Description

Explanation with an example:

1. I'll build `my-app` from source.
2. It requires some dependencies. Install them with `apt-get install foo bar baz`.
3. Build the application.
4. Install another package (`hello.deb`) which has a dependency to `foo`.
5. Remove `my-app` some time later by deleting entire source folder.
6. Remove the dependencies of `my-app`.

However, in step 6, you can't simply issue `apt-get remove foo bar baz` for the dependencies, because `hello.deb` still needs `foo` package, so only `bar` and `baz` packages should be removed.

## Proposal

In order to solve this problem, a dummy package may be created which declares the dependence of `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and we might simply install this dummy package. Later on, we can safely uninstall all those dependencies by uninstalling this dummy package. A wrapper script would build such a package on the fly and install it:

```bsh
$ apt-get-named install foo bar baz
Intention: for-myapp
```

## Question

Would this approach work for the problem? Is there any implemented solutions for such a problem? How can we create a dummy package for such a purpose?

Comment: Did you take a look at `apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: @PHD autoremove won't work here because the packages have been manually installed.

Comment: @SuperStormer Ah you are right. I didn't read the question carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no ready-made tool to provide exactly this, because the general expectation in Debian is that someone would package `my-app`, and that would be the real package ensuring the dependencies remain available as long as `my-app` is installed (independently of `hello`).

There are however two tools which can come in handy in such circumstances. I suspect the most relevant one for you is `equivs`, which provides a quick way of creating a dummy package with dependencies; see [Create a .deb package with only dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318117/86440) for details. The other tool is `mk-build-deps`, which is used to produce a dummy package reflecting another package’s build-dependencies, and is useful in slightly different scenarios: the goal is to keep a given package’s build-dependencies manageable as a unit. See [Automatically install unmet build dependencies as detected by dpkg-checkbuilddeps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416457/86440) for details.

Comment: Update: The script that exactly works as I described in the question is here: [apt-get-descriptive-install.sh](https://github.com/ceremcem/multistrap-helpers/blob/6651c8d/install-to-disk/debian-notes/package-control/apt-get-descriptive-install.sh).