# Help for script which install on Debian a package, only if is not installed

Tags: bash, debian, scripting, dpkg

I'm making a script to build a git package in Debian format (`.deb`).
This package requires the following debian packages:

cmake, libturbojpeg0-dev, libjpeg62-turbo-dev, libglx-dev, opencl-headers, libgl-dev, libegl-dev, libx11-dev, libxtst-dev, libglu1-mesa-dev, libxcb-keysyms1-dev, libxcb-glx0-dev and libx11-xcb-dev

So I am using this:

```
for file in cmake libturbojpeg0-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libglx-dev opencl-headers libgl-dev libegl-dev libx11-dev libxtst-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libx11-xcb-dev; do apt -y install $file;done
```

my question is, how to check if package is already installed and then install if is not installed?
Something like this

```
dpkg -l packagename
```

if is installed go to next,
if not use `apt -y install`.
Thanks

Comment: 1) Use `apt-get` instead of `apt` in scripts. `apt` is meant for interactive usage.

Comment: 2) If just use `apt-get -y install package1 package2 package3 ...` it will figure out by itself which packages you already have. No need for the loop and no need for the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing your own script to do this, you should list the build dependencies in the package’s control file and use `mk-build-deps` (or any package-resolving build tool, *e.g.* `pbuilder`, `sbuild` etc.). See [Automatically install unmet build dependencies as detected by dpkg-checkbuilddeps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416457/86440) for details.

If you don’t want to do that, describe the desired state and let `apt` take care of things:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends cmake libturbojpeg0-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libglx-dev opencl-headers libgl-dev libegl-dev libx11-dev libxtst-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libx11-xcb-dev
```

`apt` won’t re-install packages which are already installed, but it will upgrade any that have a newer candidate version in the repositories configured on the system (this can be disabled with the `--no-upgrade` option).

If you *really* want to write your own script, you could run `dpkg -l` for each package, and filter on `^ii` — packages which don’t match need to be installed:

```
for package in …; do
    if ! dpkg -l "$package" | grep -q ^ii; then
        sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends "$package"
    fi
done
```

(`--no-install-recommends` skips installing weak dependencies, which is what you want for build dependencies.)